# Why c# function is not working

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
   // if no link are presen the cell, 
   // we add the functionnality to select the row on the cell with a click
   cell.Attributes.Add("onclick", "x();");              

   // here we add the command to postback when the user click somewhere in the cell
   cell.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Cursor, "pointer");
   cell.Attributes.Add("title", "Select");
}
```

Actually when I call the function x which is created in c# is not executing but wen I declare in javascript it is executing what is the problem? plz let me know

Comment: where is `x` defined? did you really mean to surround it with `**`?

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow (S.O.) people here are very helpful, but you'll need to put a little more effort into asking your question in a way that people will want to and be able to answer.  Could you give a little more context for your question, and perhaps show what function `x` contains.  Try reading http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for some good ideas! Again, welcome!

Comment: @Marc, @roryf, I suspect that the asterisks were an attempt to make `x()` bold. Which in fact worked in the original version of the question but it was edited and the asterisks weren't removed. I suspect this is a classic "trying to call a C# function from a javscript onclick event client-side" question.

Comment: actually x is a function i didnt put here

Comment: @Cpfohl @user628347 look again; \*\* was in [the original version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4615b261-9d41-4676-9e4f-b9940a0c869a/view-source)

Comment: pls discuss the topic about what i said

Comment: @Marc, you are totally correct, I stand corrected and place my shoe in my...mouth...keyboard...uh, well I stand corrected anyway! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to call a server-side function from the client is with:

- A post
- AJAX (XmlHttpRequest)
- A postback

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding an onclick attribute to the HTML, this is only supposed to call a javascript function, NOT a server-side c# function.

It's been a while since I've used WebForms but as far as I remember the 'cell' object doesn't have a server-side click event.  You will have to add a Button/LinkButton or something else and attach an event handler to that.

Comment: so what i should do inorder to call the c# function?

Comment: See edit, or better still see Tim Schmelter's more complete answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the whole source-code is in a RowCreated-handler of a GridView and should allow to select a row via row-click. If i'm correct try this instead(converted from VB):

aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated" onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" onselectedindexchanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging" />
```

Codebehind

```
private void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.textDecoration='underline';";
        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';";
        e.Row.ToolTip = "click to select row";
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
    }
}
```

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged.aspx) for further informations regarding the SelectedIndexChanged- and SelctedIndexChanging-Events from GridView.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a code behind page method with Ajax and Javascript by decorating the methods with a WebMethod attribute. There is a tutorial [here](http://devarchive.net/sample_calling_page_methods_from_javascript_using_ajax_net.aspx) to do it